# How does NOORDER work on Oracle databases?

Tags: oracle, sequence

I have a sequence defined as following:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "myseq"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1046 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
```

Now my customer reported that the system generated the numbers 429521, 42952, 42967, 42968 until 42972, 42987, 4307, 4308.

The sequence is running on a clustered database system with two systems. Could this behaviour be caused by the NOORDER keyword?
The Oracle documentation for NOORDER is quite short.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This option just removes the need for the separate instances to coordinate between each other which value they will next release.

Instead, each instance gets a cache of values from which it can draw independently, which improves performance.

So in a multi-instance system you use NOORDER *unless* you want the sequence numbers to also indicate the order in which the records had a sequence number assigned to them (in general, the order in which they were inserted).

Have you correctly typed those numbers? It seems very improbable that they would come from a two-instance system with that sequence, unless only one of the instances had generated the last 40,000 or so new values, and the other had practically no activity at all.

Comment: Well, I have correctly typed those numbers from my customer's email, I cannot verify if he typed the numbers correctly though. But at least I can rule out NOORDER as the culprit with your explanation.

Comment: I suspect that they misses out a 0 ... 43007, 43008. What problem do they have with the numbers anyway? They're only key values, surely?

Comment: Missing 0 would explain the last two numbers, but not the first. So I'm not really sure what exactly the system did on his side. Our current answer is also "keep calm and ignore the gaps", the numbers are indeed nothing that really needs to be strictly continuous.

Comment: Gaps are expected with sequences. It's a common misperception that they  can be gap-free. An instance restart discards the cached numbers, the cache can (I think) get aged out of memory, a rollback will "lose" you a number ... there are all sorts of reasons why gaps appear.